# PostgreSQL 10.4 Installation error

Tags: installation, postgresql-10

I have downloaded PostgreSQL 10.4 from its official website. While I am trying to install its exe as admin, it gives following prompt error. Same issue is observed when I am trying to install 9.6.9. Mys system is having all the admin rights and no firewall is set on my system.

[image]

Comment: Maybe your virus check prevents that?

Comment: All antivirus' are disabled

Comment: The Postgres version you are trying to install **is** 10.4 there is no version "10.4.1" - Postgres dropped the third digit from the version number with version 10: https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/